# Dice Roll Probability of winning

Tags: probability, statistics

Dice A sides: 4, 4, 4, 4, 13, 13

Dice B sides: 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9

If I roll both dice

Which dice is more likely to win here? How can I approach this?

Comment: There are four possible pairs of values, each with an easily calculated probability.  Can you find them?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably winning means getting the larger number.  As stated dice B numbers are all in between both dice A numbers.  2/3 of A rolls are 4 (A loses), while 1/3 are 13 (A wins).  So A wins 1/3 of the time.

Answer (score 0):

If A rolls a 13, then A wins.  If A rolls a 4, then B wins.  The probability A rolls a 13 is 2/6 and the probability A rolls a 4 is 4/6.